# How do i teleport (wormy.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x

in the code below i have created 2 blocks(wallCoords1 and wallCoords2). Now i want the worm to teleport when it hit one of the blocks to the other block(Like when the worm hits the wall).

This is what i tried but it isn't working:

```
if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == wallCoords1 or wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == wallCoords1:
            if direction1 == UP:
                newHead = {'x': wallCoords2, 'y': wallCoords2 - 1}
            elif direction1 == DOWN:
                newHead = {'x': wallCoords2, 'y': wallCoords2}
            elif direction1 == LEFT:
                newHead = {'x': wallCoords2 - 1, 'y': wallCoords2}
            elif direction1 == RIGHT:
                newHead = {'x': wallCoords2, 'y': wallCoords2}
            worm1 = True
```

Any sugestions what hes to be changed? or why the snake is still going true th blocks?

Code is runned with Mu editor

````
# By Al Sweigart al@inventwithpython.com
# http://inventwithpython.com/pygame
# Released under a "Simplified BSD" license

import random, pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 15
WINDOWWIDTH = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
CELLSIZE = 20
assert WINDOWWIDTH % CELLSIZE == 0, "Window width must be a multiple of cell size."
assert WINDOWHEIGHT % CELLSIZE == 0, "Window height must be a multiple of cell size."
CELLWIDTH = int(WINDOWWIDTH / CELLSIZE)
CELLHEIGHT = int(WINDOWHEIGHT / CELLSIZE)

#             R    G    B
WHITE     = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK     = (  0,   0,   0)
RED       = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN     = (  0, 255,   0)
DARKGREEN = (  0, 155,   0)
DARKGRAY  = ( 40,  40,  40)
BGCOLOR = BLACK

UP = 'up'
DOWN = 'down'
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

HEAD = 0 # syntactic sugar: index of the worm's head

def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, BASICFONT

    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Wormy')

    showStartScreen()
    while True:
        runGame()
        showGameOverScreen()


def runGame():
    worm1 = False
    # Set a random start point.
    startx = random.randint(5, CELLWIDTH - 6)
    starty = random.randint(5, CELLHEIGHT - 6)
    wormCoords = [{'x': startx,     'y': starty},
                  {'x': startx - 1, 'y': starty},
                  {'x': startx - 2, 'y': starty}]
    direction1 = RIGHT

    wallCoords1 = [{'x': 2,     'y': 2}]
    wallCoords2 = [{'x': 29,     'y': 21}]



    # Start the apple in a random place.
    apple = getRandomLocation()

    while True:  # main game loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():  # event handling loop
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key == K_LEFT) and direction1 != RIGHT:  # snake 1
                    direction1 = LEFT
                elif (event.key == K_RIGHT) and direction1 != LEFT:
                    direction1 = RIGHT
                elif (event.key == K_UP) and direction1 != DOWN:
                    direction1 = UP
                elif (event.key == K_DOWN) and direction1 != UP:
                    direction1 = DOWN

        # check if the worm1 has hit itself or the edge
        if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == -1 or wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == CELLWIDTH or wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == -1 or \
                wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == CELLHEIGHT:
            if direction1 == UP:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': CELLHEIGHT - 1}
            elif direction1 == DOWN:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': 0}
            elif direction1 == LEFT:
                newHead = {'x': CELLWIDTH - 1, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}
            elif direction1 == RIGHT:
                newHead = {'x': 0, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}
            worm1 = True




        if not worm1:
            if direction1 == UP:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] - 1}
            elif direction1 == DOWN:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] + 1}
            elif direction1 == LEFT:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] - 1, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}
            elif direction1 == RIGHT:
                newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] + 1, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}
        else:
            worm1 = False












        # check if worm has eaten an apply
        if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == apple['x'] and wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == apple['y']:
            # don't remove worm's tail segment
            apple = getRandomLocation() # set a new apple somewhere
        else:
            del wormCoords[-1] # remove worm's tail segment



        wormCoords.insert(0, newHead)
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        drawGrid()
        drawWorm(wormCoords)
        drawWall(wallCoords1)
        drawWall(wallCoords2)
        drawApple(apple)
        drawScore(len(wormCoords) - 3)
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

def drawPressKeyMsg():
    pressKeySurf = BASICFONT.render('Press a key to play.', True, DARKGRAY)
    pressKeyRect = pressKeySurf.get_rect()
    pressKeyRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH - 200, WINDOWHEIGHT - 30)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect)


def checkForKeyPress():
    if len(pygame.event.get(QUIT)) > 0:
        terminate()

    keyUpEvents = pygame.event.get(KEYUP)
    if len(keyUpEvents) == 0:
        return None
    if keyUpEvents[0].key == K_ESCAPE:
        terminate()
    return keyUpEvents[0].key


def showStartScreen():
    titleFont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 100)
    titleSurf1 = titleFont.render('Wormy!', True, WHITE, DARKGREEN)
    titleSurf2 = titleFont.render('Wormy!', True, GREEN)

    degrees1 = 0
    degrees2 = 0
    while True:
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
        rotatedSurf1 = pygame.transform.rotate(titleSurf1, degrees1)
        rotatedRect1 = rotatedSurf1.get_rect()
        rotatedRect1.center = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT / 2)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(rotatedSurf1, rotatedRect1)

        rotatedSurf2 = pygame.transform.rotate(titleSurf2, degrees2)
        rotatedRect2 = rotatedSurf2.get_rect()
        rotatedRect2.center = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT / 2)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(rotatedSurf2, rotatedRect2)

        drawPressKeyMsg()

        if checkForKeyPress():
            pygame.event.get() # clear event queue
            return
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
        degrees1 += 3 # rotate by 3 degrees each frame
        degrees2 += 7 # rotate by 7 degrees each frame


def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()


def getRandomLocation():
    return {'x': random.randint(0, CELLWIDTH - 1), 'y': random.randint(0, CELLHEIGHT - 1)}


def showGameOverScreen():
    gameOverFont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 150)
    gameSurf = gameOverFont.render('Game', True, WHITE)
    overSurf = gameOverFont.render('Over', True, WHITE)
    gameRect = gameSurf.get_rect()
    overRect = overSurf.get_rect()
    gameRect.midtop = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, 10)
    overRect.midtop = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, gameRect.height + 10 + 25)

    DISPLAYSURF.blit(gameSurf, gameRect)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(overSurf, overRect)
    drawPressKeyMsg()
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(500)
    checkForKeyPress() # clear out any key presses in the event queue

    while True:
        if checkForKeyPress():
            pygame.event.get() # clear event queue
            return

def drawScore(score):
    scoreSurf = BASICFONT.render('Score: %s' % (score), True, WHITE)
    scoreRect = scoreSurf.get_rect()
    scoreRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH - 120, 10)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(scoreSurf, scoreRect)


def drawWorm(wormCoords):
    for coord in wormCoords:
        x = coord['x'] * CELLSIZE
        y = coord['y'] * CELLSIZE
        wormSegmentRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGREEN, wormSegmentRect)
        wormInnerSegmentRect = pygame.Rect(x + 4, y + 4, CELLSIZE - 8, CELLSIZE - 8)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN, wormInnerSegmentRect)

def drawWall(wallCoords):
    for coord in wallCoords:
        x = coord['x'] * CELLSIZE
        y = coord['y'] * CELLSIZE
        wallSegmentRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, WHITE, wallSegmentRect)

def drawApple(coord):
    x = coord['x'] * CELLSIZE
    y = coord['y'] * CELLSIZE
    appleRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, RED, appleRect)


def drawGrid():
    for x in range(0, WINDOWWIDTH, CELLSIZE): # draw vertical lines
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGRAY, (x, 0), (x, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    for y in range(0, WINDOWHEIGHT, CELLSIZE): # draw horizontal lines
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGRAY, (0, y), (WINDOWWIDTH, y))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```
````

Answer (score 1):

```
----------
|    ||  |
|    ||  |
| wwh||n |
----------
```

`w` is the worms body, `h` the worm's head, `n` the new position for the head.
So assume the worm is moving to the right, when you detect a collision to the wall, the new position for the worm's head won't be the position of the wall, instead it'll be the one to the right - if it's free. If it's not, then try again one further to the right. Repeat this until you find a free space.

To check if the worm has hit the wall

1. Put all walls into an array `wallCoords = [{'x': 2, 'y': 2}, {'x': 29, 'y':2}]`
2. Check if the `newHead` position equals any of these `wallCoords`, if so, move the head on one more:

```py
newHead = # assign to new position as you already do
while newHead in wallCoords:
  if direction1 == RIGHT:
    newHead["x"] += 1
  else ... # other directions
```

This loop will end after `max(WIDTH,HEIGHT)` iterations since the snake-head is currently at a wall-free location.

After this you'll have to check if the new location doesn't collide with the snake itself again. This can be done the same way as with the wall collision.
Only then can you assign the snake head to that new position

Comment: You'll need to put the walls in an array and then loop over them, see my edit.

Comment: I tried adding this and deleted the newHead = and the else, just to check if the right direction is working, but i get this error:

 line 111, in runGame
    newHead.x += 1
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'x'

Comment: Could it be that `newHead` does not have the attributes `x`/`y` for some reason? Are you forgetting to assign it or have misspelled them somewhere? Why not put a breakpoint before the error happens or `print(newHead)` so that you know what's in the head before it chrashes.

Comment: It has x/y when i print it.

Comment: This is the code ```        while newHead in wallCoords1:
            if direction1 == RIGHT:
                newHead.x += 1```

Comment: Are you printing it in the `while` loop?

Comment: If this answer helped you solve the problem please consider marking it as the `most helpful answer` :)

Comment: wich while loop?

Comment: The one it crashes. Probably you'll want to insert `print(newHead)` directly before or after `while newHead in wallCoords:` (if it is crashing in that loop).

Comment: Ah, sorry. Because `newHead` is a dictionary and not an instance of an object it does not have attributes `.x` or .`y` - instead you have to access them via `newHead["x"]` and `newHead["y"]` (see revised answer)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I found a solution:

```
    print(newHead)
    while newHead in wallCoords1:
        if direction1 == RIGHT:
            newHead = {'x': 29, 'y':2}

        elif direction1 == LEFT:
                newHead = {'x': 29, 'y':2}
```